# In VHDL, Is it possible to reference a static variable using an access reference?

Tags: vhdl

In VHDL, Is it possible to reference a static variable using an access reference?

Most of the examples I've seen with VHDL accesses involve allocating memory dynamically.  I was curious if you can also get the access handle to a statically allocated variable.  Like if I had a global integer in a particular architecture that is allocated statically,  Could I assign a reference to that variable to an access type for integer?

Comment: Tricky's answer is correct, however this doesn't allow you to "redirect" the alias to another variable elsewhere in the program. Ada does allow this with  `my_ptr : access all integer;` and `my_var : aliased integer;` allowing the pointer to point to the variable with `my_ptr := my_var'access;` but nobody considered VHDL to be usable as a system programming language, so it didn't inherit that. You are stuck with allocation via 'new'. Can you be clearer about a use case where neither of these is satisfactory?

Comment: No.  Doesn't meet the requirement in IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.6.2 Simple variable assignments, 10.6.2.1 General "If the target of the variable assignment statement is a name, then the name shall denote a variable, and the  type of the expression on the right-hand side shall be the same as the base type of the variable denoted by that name."  The only way to get a value of an access type is through allocation (9.3.7 Allocators). There's no way to reach into kernel space (no predefined attribute) to derive an access value for an object declared of a non-access type.

Answer (score 0):

No such thing in VHDL exists. You cannot get a "handle" to another variable for an `access` type. You can only create dynamic memory into an `access` type.

But, VHDL does have aliases. With these, you can create an alias to anything visible. And using external names (from VHDL 2008) you can create an alias to any object that is not directly visible. For example:

```vhdl
entity ent1
end entity ent1;

architecture arch of ent1 is
  constant SOME_CONST : integer := 7;

  alias my_alias : integer is SOME_CONST;
begin
  process
  begin
    report "ent1 alias = " & to_string(my_alias);
    wait;
  end process;
end architecture;

entity ent2 is
end entity ent2;

architecture arch of ent2 is
begin
  inst : entity work.ent1;

  process
    alias a is << constant inst.SOME_CONST : integer >>;
  begin
    report "ent2 alias = " & to_string(a);
    wait;
  end process;
end architecture;
```